# Timing Effiency Test of Selection Sort slow in Begin

Tags: java, sorting, timing, selection-sort

I'm timing the effiency of a selection sort. But the timing in the beginning is very long. Here are the results of the effiency timing of the selection sort.

```
Run: | 100 : 560128 nanoseconds |
Run: | 200 : 3072 nanoseconds |
Run: | 400 : 1707 nanoseconds |
Run: | 800 : 1707 nanoseconds |
Run: | 1600 : 1365 nanoseconds |
Run: | 3200 : 1365 nanoseconds |
Run: | 6400 : 1707 nanoseconds |
Run: | 12800 : 1365 nanoseconds |
Run: | 25600 : 1365 nanoseconds |
Run: | 51200 : 1365 nanoseconds |
Run: | 102400 : 1707 nanoseconds |
Run: | 204800 : 1707 nanoseconds |
Run: | 409600 : 1366 nanoseconds |
Run: | 819200 : 1707 nanoseconds |
Run: | 1638400 : 4437 nanoseconds |
Run: | 3276800 : 5120 nanoseconds |
```

You can clearly see at the array size of 100 the timing is 560128 nanoseconds.
Then at the array size of 200 it drops down to 3072 nanoseconds. Why does the timing take so long in the beginning and drops after the list size is 200? Because this shouldn't be the right timing for a selection sort.

This is the method I wrote for the effiency test on the selection sort:

```
    public void testQuicksort() {
        for (int archerAmount = 100; archerAmount < 5000000; archerAmount *= 2) {
            List<Archer> unsortedArchersForSelInSort = new ArrayList<>(archerAmount);
            StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
            timer.reset();
            timer.start();
            List<Archer> sortedArchersSelInSort = ChampionSelector.selInsSort(unsortedArchersForSelInSort, comparator);
            timer.stop();
            System.out.printf("Run: | %d : %d nanoseconds |\n", archerAmount, timer.getNanoTime());
        }
    }
```

This is the selection sort:

```
public static List<Archer> selInsSort(List<Archer> archers, Comparator<Archer> scoringScheme) {

        for (int i = 0; i < archers.size(); i++)
        {
            int minArcherIndex = i;

            for (int a = i; a < archers.size(); a++)
            {
                if (scoringScheme.compare(archers.get(minArcherIndex), archers.get(a)) > 0)
                {
                    minArcherIndex = a;
                }
            }

            Archer swapArcher = archers.get(i);

            archers.set(i, archers.get(minArcherIndex));
            archers.set(minArcherIndex, swapArcher);

        }

        return archers;
    }
```

The Stopwatch I used: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html

Comment: Perhaps the _Java Microbenchmark Harness_ (JMH) is more appropriate?